# Render categories and subcategories rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a list with user registration

There are three class:

```
User(id: integer, name: string, email: string, password_digest: string, remember_token: string)
TaskList(id: integer, user_id: integer, header: string)
Task(id: integer, task_list_id: integer, content: string, mark: boolean, priority: integer)
```

Theirs model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_lists, dependent: :destroy
end

class TaskList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task_list
end
```

How to display a list of tasks for each user

```
each user
  - TaskList(user_id)
     Task(task_list_id)
     Task
  - TaskList(user_id)
     Task
     Task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance variable set for the user then something like this will achieve what you want.

```
<% @user.task_lists.each do |list| %>
  <h1><%= list.header %></h1>
  <% list.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <p><%= task.content %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end >
```